# Trying to bold within this column

Tags: html

I am trying to make the title in this column bold, can i tried specifying the style as bold and it just disappeared, any way i can do this within this column.

```
[column parallax_bg="disabled" parallax_bg_inertia="-0.2" 
extended="false"extended_padding="true" background_color=""
background_image="" background_repeat="" background_position="
background_size="auto" background_attachment="" hide_bg_lowres="false" 
background_video="" vertical_padding_top="0" vertical_padding_bottom="0" 
more_link="" more_text="" left_border="transparent" class="" id="" title="We 
are based in Oakville, Ontario" title_type="single" animation="none" 
width="1/1" last="true"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you meant making the text bold in the column you can try this:

```
#column {
font-weight:bold;
}
```

where #column is the id of the column specified in your html.

Answer (score 0):

In html around the worlds you want bold you can but

```
<b>.......</b>
```

the world between those tags will be bold.

Comment: `<b>` and `<i>` should be avoided because they describe the style of the text. Instead, use `<strong>` and `<em>` because that describes the semantics (the meaning) of the text.

Comment: <b> does not  need to be avoided it has its place.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to bold your text.

```
<strong>We are based in Oakville, Ontario</strong>
```

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xjeqmsbr/